Special character (\char") in index : bad display
I'm currently compiling an index for my thesis in which I list languages that don't have a Latin alphabet. This is the case for Mycenaean Greek, where I have to declare each character with the command \char".
My preamble is as follow :
\setotherlanguage{myc}
\newfontfamily\mycfont[Path=./Fonts/Mycaenean/]{Aegean.ttf}

and the text in my chapter is :
comme dans 
   \textmyc{\char"1003A\char"1001C}
\textit{wo-no} ‘vin’

It is displayed correctly as :

Now, when I add the index command:
comme dans 
   \textmyc{\char"1003A\char"1001C}
       \index[mots]{Grec!wono@\textmyc{\char"1003A\char"1001C}} wo-no \emph{(myc.)}
\textit{wo-no} ‘vin’

It displays badly (the text after @ is partially displayed) :

And in my index, this appears (I use imakeidx):

Clearly, the letters associated with the codes of these characters are not understood as part of the code by the index, but as a letter in its own.
I hope someone can find a solution to this problem!

The main problem is that " is a special character for MakeIndex.
I suggest a different strategy. There's no point in \setotherlanguage with an unsupported one, but it's more important to have a simpler syntax for the \textmyc command.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

% replace the following with your preferred Mycenean font
\newfontface{\linearBfont}{NotoSansLinearB-Regular}[
  Path=/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/,
  Extension=.ttf,
]

\makeindex[name=mots]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\textmyc}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \linearBfont\seq_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_seq \__youyou_linearb:n
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__youyou_linearb:n { \symbol{"100#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\index[mots]{a}
\index[mots]{u}
\index[mots]{v}
\index[mots]{w}
\index[mots]{x}
\index[mots]{y}

comme dans 
\textmyc{3A,1C}%
\index[mots]{Grec!wono@\textmyc{3A,1C}} wo-no \emph{(myc.)}
\textit{wo-no} ‘vin’

\printindex[mots]

\end{document}

The idea is that the Linear B block starts from U+10000, so you can name the glyphs with just the last two hexadecimal digits.
Main document

Index


Thank you very much, it works perfectly !
